# Как при помощи CSS сделать картинку черно-белой?

Tags: css3, css

Здравствуйте. Как при помощи CSS сделать картинку черно-белой?

*UPD1*:
Инструменты серверного программирования недоступны. Только клиентский CSS.

Comment: С помощью одного лишь CSS врятли тут еще с JS надо повозится. Вот небольшой пример - [тыц](http://jusweb.ru/jquery_javascript/31-cherno-beloe-izobrazhenie-pri-pomoschi-jquery-i-css.html)

Comment: Это не делает картинку черно-белой) Там их 2 на каждую.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мб объяснить заказчику, что браузер - не фотошоп?)

А вообще вот, [html5+css3+js](http://spyrestudios.com/html5-canvas-image-effects-black-white/)

Answer (score 19):

Используйте CSS:

```
filter: grayscale(100%);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use it

```
-webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
-moz-filter: grayscale(100%);
-ms-filter: grayscale(100%);
-o-filter: grayscale(100%);
filter: grayscale(100%);
filter: url(grayscale.svg); /* Firefox 4+ */
filter: gray; /* IE 6-9 */
```

Comment: Откуда такой набор префиксов? [Не вижу](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-filters), чтобы они вообще существовали, кроме webkit.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?